# Sublimetext Database overview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext3

I have been evaluating Rubymine recently which is an amazing IDE, probably the most complete for Rails. Though I think I prefer the ergonomy of SublimeText and all its customizable packages.

Though I really miss one feature: the database tab on the right that gives me an up-to-date overview of my database structure and records.

I can't find a similar package for SublimeText and was wondering if it existed at all ?

Comment: A web search didn't help? I mean, I don't even use Sublime that much anymore, and I found a couple that may or may not suit your needs in like 30 seconds. In any case, OT for SO.

Comment: What's missing in `db/structure.sql` or `db/your_app.yml`?

Comment: Hi medik, I don't have any `structure.sql` or `my_app.yml`. I guess this is because it is a PG database. I do have `schema.rb` though and can surely launch Pgadmin4. Was just hoping for something more user friendly. Hi Dave, I have seen a few Postgres packages but not any with a description that could match. I will try and see though..

Comment: I haven't seen any atom packages that have that capability -- I know they have SQL-to-Text clients. I used to use RubyMine but found that atom/sublime with a PG client (PG Commander) fit my work flow best.